# A question about O.D.E. $x'=-x(t^2-x^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that the differential equation $$x'=-x(t^2-x^2)$$ is given. And some solution $x(t)$ satisfies that for some $t_0$ we have $|x(t_0)|<t_0$. We have to prove that $|x(t)|<t$ for all $t>t_0$.

**My approach:** This O.D.E. have a trivial solution $x(t)\equiv 0$, and the result follows in this case. Then we analyze the critical points given by solve: 
$$x'=-x(t^2-x^2)=0$$
which gives the solutions: ($x\equiv 0$, $x^2=t^2\Rightarrow x=\pm t$). Then the solutions of the O.D.E. satisfies that have a maximum or minimum in this linear functions. If that is correct, how can we identify it and continue this problem?

Any help is welcome, or another ideas too. Thanks

Comment: Can I assume $t_0 \ge 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume $t_0 > 0$.  Suppose that there exists $t > t_0$ such that $|x(t)| = |t|$.  Let $t_1 = \inf\{t>t_0:|x(t)| = |t|\}$.  Then $x'(t_1) = 0$, and hence $x(t_1 + \epsilon) = \pm t_1 + O(\epsilon^2)$, which means that for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$ we have $|x(t_1 - \epsilon)| > |t_1 - \epsilon|$, contradicting the definition of $t_1$.